# Unused JavaScript arguments

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript. And I want to make sense of a feature in JavaScript. Please consider the following example:

```
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log(this.name +" :Hello, human.");
}
var max = new Dog("Max", "Buddy")
max.bark();
```

As you can see two arguments were passed into making a new dog object while only one (name) was required. 
I know that the second argument is unused, but where is it stored/ is there any utility to passing an extra argument?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you are not using "strict-mode" then you can access all the arguments passed by to the function in `arguments` array inside function.

Comment: Thanks, guys. So how does JS read the line where I create new Dog object max -- specifically what does it do when it reads "Buddy" and what does it do to it, or JS won't even read it?

Answer (score 2):

They can be retrieved in the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> `arguments` is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that
>   contains the values of the arguments passed to that function.

```js
function Dog(name) {
  console.log(arguments);
  this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log(this.name +" :Hello, human.");
}
var max = new Dog("Max", "Buddy");
max.bark();
```

The modern alternative would be the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
function Dog(...names) {
  console.log(names);
}
var max = new Dog("Max", "Buddy");
```

Answer (score 0):

They are store in `arguments` array :

```js
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name
  console.log(arguments)
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log(this.name +" :Hello, human.");
}
var max = new Dog("Max", "Buddy", "Arm", {name: "Jacob"})
max.bark();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using js in strict mode you can access the arguments property of function.

```js
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name
  // all the arguments are inside arguments property of function
  console.log(arguments);
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log(this.name +" :Hello, human.");
}
var max = new Dog("Max", "Buddy")
max.bark();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamic language. Same function can accept dynamic arguments. There are multiple way to access all variable passed 2 a function/constructor.

1. Using [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).
2. Using vaargs or [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).
3. Mix of rest operator and arguments.

It depends how you want to use the values. See the below examples.

```js
function DogArgs(name) {
  this.name = name;
  console.log(arguments); // array like structure [Arguments] { '0': 'Max', '1': 'Buddy' }
}

function DogRest(...names) {
  this.name = names[0];
  console.log(names); // Array [ 'Max', 'Buddy' ]
}
function DogPartialRest(name, ...others) {
  this.name = name;
  console.log(others); // Array [ 'Buddy' ]
}

var max1 = new DogArgs("Max", "Buddy");
var max2 = new DogRest("Max", "Buddy");
var max3 = new DogPartialRest("Max", "Buddy");
```

**Example 1: Using arguments**

```
function sum() {
  const values = Array.from(arguments); // convertin array, since arguments is not array
  return values.reduce((sum, val) => (sum += val), 0);
}
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4)); // 10
```

**Example 2: Using vaargs or rest operator.**

```
function sum(...values) {
  return values.reduce((sum, val) => (sum += val), 0);
}
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4)); // 10
```

**Example 3: Mix of rest operator and arguments**

```
function Person(name, age, ...rest) {
  this.name = name
  this.age = age
  this.salary = 0
  if(rest.length) {
    this.salary = rest[0]
    this.address = rest[1] || ''
  }
}
console.log(new Person("deepak", 30)) // Person { name: 'deepak', age: 30, salary: 0 }
console.log(new Person("deepak", 30, 2000)) // Person { name: 'deepak', age: 30, salary: 2000, address: '' }
```